# Fitting data with Voigt profile in lmfit in python - huge errors

Tags: convolution, gaussian, errorbar, lmfit, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to fit some RIXS data with Voigt profiles (lmfit in Python), and I have defined the Voigt profile in the following way:

```
def gfunction_norm(x, pos, gwid):
    gauss= (1/(gwid*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*(np.exp((-1.0/2)*((((x-pos)/gwid))**2)))
    return (gauss-gauss.min())/(gauss.max()-gauss.min())

def lfunction_norm(x,pos,lwid):
    lorentz=(0.15915*lwid)/((x-pos)**2+0.25*lwid**2)
    return (lorentz-lorentz.min())/(lorentz.max()-lorentz.min())



def voigt(x, pos, gwid, lwid, int):
    step=0.005
    x2=np.arange(pos-7,pos+7+step,step)
    voigt3=np.convolve(gfunction_norm(x2, pos, gwid), lfunction_norm(x2, pos, lwid), mode='same')   
    norm=(voigt3-voigt3.min())/(voigt3.max()-voigt3.min()) 
    y=np.interp(energy, x2, norm)
    return y * int
```

I have used this definition instead of the popular Voigt profile definition in Python:

```
def voigt(x, alpha, cen, gamma): 
    sigma=alpha/np.sqrt(2*np.log(2))
    return np.real(wofz((x-cen+1j*gamma)/sigma/np.sqrt(2)))/(sigma*2.51)
```

because it gives me more clarity on the intensity of the peaks etc.

Now, I have a couple of spectra with 9-10 peaks and I am trying to fit all of them with Voigt profiles (precisely in the way I defined it).

Now, I have a couple of questions:

1. Do you think my Voigt definition is OK? What (dis)advantages do I have by using the convolution instead of the approximative second definition?
2. As a result of my fit, sometimes I get crazy large standard deviations. For example, these are best-fit parameters for one of the peaks:

```
    int8:    0.00986265 +/- 0.00113104 (11.47%) (init = 0.05)
    pos8:   -2.57960013 +/- 0.00790640 (0.31%) (init = -2.6)
    gwid8:   0.06613237 +/- 0.02558441 (38.69%) (init = 0.1)
    lwid8:   1.0909e-04 +/- 1.48706395 (1363160.91%) (init = 0.001)
```

(intensity, position, gaussian and lorentzian width respectively).
Does this output mean that this peak should be purely gaussian?

3. I have noticed that large errors usually happen when the best-fit parameter is very small. Does this have something to do with the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm that is used by default in lmfit? I should note that I sometimes have the same problem even when I use the other definition of the Voigt profile (and not just for Lorentzian widths).
   Here is a part of the code (it is a part of a bigger code and it is in a for loop, meaning I use same initial values for multiple similar spectra):

```
    model = Model(final)
    result = model.fit(spectra[:,nb_spectra], params, x=energy)
    print(result.fit_report())
```

"final" is the sum of many voigt profiles that I previously defined.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a duplicate or follow-up to [Lmfit fit produces huge uncertainties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74866212/lmfit-fit-produces-huge-uncertainties) - please use on SO question per topic.

> Do you think my Voigt definition is OK? What (dis)advantages do I have by using the convolution instead of the approximative second definition?

What makes you say that the second definition is approximate?  In some sense, all floating-point calculations are approximate, but the Faddeeva function from `scipy.special.wofz` *is* the analytic solution for the Voigt profile.  Doing the convolution yourself is likely to be a bit slower and is also an approximation (at the machine-precision level).

Since you are using Lmfit, I would recommend using its `VoigtModel` which will make your life easier: it uses `scipy.special.wofz` and parameter names that make it easy to switch to other profiles (say, `GaussianModel`).

You did not give a very complete example of code (for reference, a minimal, working version of actual code is more or less expected on SO and highly recommended), but that might look something like

```
from lmfit.models import VoigtModel

model = VoigtModel(prefix='p1_') + VoigtModel(prefix='p2_') + ...
```

> As a result of my fit, sometimes I get crazy large standard
> deviations. For example, these are best-fit parameters for one of the
> peaks:
>
> ```
>    int8:    0.00986265 +/- 0.00113104 (11.47%) (init = 0.05)
>    pos8:   -2.57960013 +/- 0.00790640 (0.31%) (init = -2.6)
>    gwid8:   0.06613237 +/- 0.02558441 (38.69%) (init = 0.1)
>    lwid8:   1.0909e-04 +/- 1.48706395 (1363160.91%) (init = 0.001)
> ```

> (intensity, position, gaussian and lorentzian width respectively).
> Does this output mean that this peak should be purely gaussian?

First, that may not be a "crazy large" standard deviation - it sort of depends on the data and rest of the fit.  Perhaps the value for `int8` is really, really small, and heavily overlapped with other peaks -- it might be highly correlated with other variables.  But, it may very well mean that the peak is more Gaussian-like.

Since you are analyzing X-ray scattering data, the use of a Voigt function is probably partially justified with the idea (assertion, assumption, expectation?) that the material response would give a Gaussian profile, while the instrumentation (including X-ray source) would give a Lorentzian broadening.  That suggests that the Lorentzian width might be the same for the various peaks, or perhaps parameterized as a simple function of the incident and scattering wavelengths or `q` values.  That is, you might be able to (and may be better off) constrain the values of the Lorentzian width (your `lwid`, I think, or `gamma` in `lmfit.models.VoigtModel`) to all be the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! There definitely seems to be a large correlation between the gaussian and lorentzian width wherever the lorentzian width uncertainty is too large. 
Also, do you happen to know if the resolution varies across the energy loss spectrum for RIXS?